# How to assign variable value to 2D Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

For my homework assignment I am supposed to take 3 inputs, `x`, `y`, and `m`. `x` and `y` are the dimensions of the array `monsters`, and `m` is of type `Monster`. I am supposed to take the input, and as long as the `Monster` is a default `Monster` (i.e., the name is `""`, and the level is `-1`), I assign the value at `monsters[y][x]`.

In a later method I will have to print the array's info so that when it appears on screen it will show the initials of the name, as well as its level. it would look like this if the array was a `2x2` and all the monsters have the same name and level:

```
V(5) V(5)

V(5) V(5)
```

My code so far is as follows:

```
public void updateMonster(int x, int y, Monster m){
    String name = m.getName();
    int lvl = m.getLevel();

    if(y <= gridWidth || x <= gridHeight){
        if (name == "" && lvl == -1){
            monsters[y][x] = m;
        } 

    }

}
```

Obviously, I can't just declare `monsters[y][x] = m;` because `m` is not an integer, and I can't assign a non-integer value to an array.

How would I go about taking the name and level and assigning it specifically to the location at `monsters[y][x]`?

I thought of possibly doing a variation of the values by multiplying them together so the value of `monsters[1][0] = 1 * 0`, and then when I print the array it would just call the multiplied number, but that wouldn't work because of duplicates.

Here is the whole class including the declaration of variables.

```
public class Dungeon {
  private int[][] monsters;
  int gridWidth;
  int gridHeight;
public Dungeon(int width, int height){
    monsters = new int[width][height];
    gridWidth = width;
    gridHeight = height;
}
public void updateMonster(int x, int y, Monster m){
    String name = m.getName();
    int lvl = m.getLevel();

    if(y <= gridWidth || x <= gridHeight){
        if (name == "" && lvl == -1){
            monsters[y][x] = m;
        }

}

}
public void swap(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){

}
public void shuffle(){

}
public void shift(char command){

}
public String printInfo(){
    return null;

}
}
```

Comment: well the initial declaration of monsters is: private int[][] monsters;

Comment: Any reason `monsters` is an array of `int`s and not of `Monster`s? In other words, is there a reason you don't simply declare it as `private Monster[][] monsters;`?

Comment: By the way, use `name.isEmpty()` and not `name == ""`